# Categorize the total amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gave me a list of store names and its respective amounts. However I would like to sum and categorize the amounts like this:

Store Name | $0-$50 | $50 - $100 | $100 - $500 | $500+

Based on the following screenshot:

[image]

Here is my condition:

```
If the TotalAmount for the store is between $0-$50, then it will be summed and go into $0-$50 bucket
If the TotalAmount for the store is between $50-$100, then it will be summed and go into $50-$100 bucket
If the TotalAmount for the store is between $100-$500, then it will be summed and go into $100-$500 bucket
If the TotalAmount for the store is greater than $500, then it will be summed and go into $500+ bucket
```

Here is my basic query for the above snapshot

```
Select 
    s.StoreName
    , r.TotalAmount
    --, SUM(r.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
FROM
    Store s
        join ShoppingList sl on s.StoreId = sl.StoreId
        join Purchase p on p.ShoppingListId = sl.ShoppingListId
        join Receipt r on r.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation. Not clear what you want to do about values which are on the border, I will leave that to you:

```sql
Select 
    s.StoreName
    , SUM(CASE WHEN r.TotalAmount >= 0 AND r.TotalAmount <= 50 THEN r.TotalAmount END) as [$0 - $50]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN r.TotalAmount > 50 AND r.TotalAmount <= 100 THEN r.TotalAmount END) as [$50 - $100]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN r.TotalAmount > 100 AND r.TotalAmount <= 500 THEN r.TotalAmount END) as [$100 - $500]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN r.TotalAmount > 500 THEN r.TotalAmount END) as [$500+]
FROM
    Store s
        join ShoppingList sl on s.StoreId = sl.StoreId
        join Purchase p on p.ShoppingListId = sl.ShoppingListId
        join Receipt r on r.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId
GROUP BY
     s.StoreId,    -- always use a unique column for aggregation
     s.StoreName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.StoreName,x.TotalAmount,
 case 
   when x.TotalAmount between 0 and 50 then '0-50'
   when x.TotalAmount between 51 and 100 then '50-100'
   when x.TotalAmount between 101 and 150 then '100-150'
end as Bucket
 from 
 (
   Select 
   s.StoreName
    , SUM(r.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
    FROM
    Store s
    join ShoppingList sl on s.StoreId = sl.StoreId
    join Purchase p on p.ShoppingListId = sl.ShoppingListId
    join Receipt r on r.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId
    group by s.StoreName
)as x
```

Comment: Thanks for this query but this is not exactly what I am looking for. Based on the snapshot that I posted, if the TotalAmount (column) is in the range, it will be summed and put in the appropriate bucket as I mentioned in the condition. Also, I am looking for a categorized columns like this: Store Name | $0-$50 | $50 - $100 | $100 - $500 | $500+

Comment: OK. You have three rows for CostCo (452.67,419.59 and 287.57). What result do you want for them?

Comment: Since those amounts are in the $100 - $500 range, they will be summed ($1159.83) and put into the $100 - $500 bucket. Suppose I got a store, lets say Lowe's with TotalAmounts (55.99, 10.99, 12.99, 80.99)...So here 55.99+80.99 = 136.98 will go into the $50 - $100 bucket and the others 10.99+12.99 will go into the $0-$50 bucket. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Anyway `BETWEEN` isn't going to work for decimals, you need a half open interval